# PHP: Create dynamic variable name using array value and string text

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop, dynamic-arrays

I'm working on a PHP project that takes data from a massive form (thousands of inputs -- only I use it, and it hides/disables inputs that aren't in use) and uses it to generate HTML for emails.

With so much possible data coming in from the form, rather than creating variables for all possible inputs, I'm trying to write a PHP script that only takes the data from the sections included in that email to create variables which can then be passed into the HTML generation script.

However, I've run into a roadblock trying to dynamically create the variable names from the sections in use.

Here's a look at what I've come up with:

```
//Data coming in from a form on sections being used
$nosections = $_POST['nosections']; // The number of sections in the email (from 1-6)
$sectionblock1 = $_POST['sectionblock1']; // The module of the first section (e.g. "beerspecial")
...
$sectionblock6 = $_POST['sectionblock6']; // the last possible section module

// An array collecting all of the sections selected in the form.
$sectionsarray = array(1 => $sectionblock1, 2=> $sectionblock2, 3 => $sectionblock3, 4 => $sectionblock4, 5 => $sectionblock5, 6 => $sectionblock6);

//loop based on number of sections in use
if (isset($nosections)) {
for($i=1; $i<=$nosections; $i++) {

    // for product sections, which all have the same inputs
    if((${'sectionblock'.$i} != 'events') || (${'sectionblock'.$i} != 'other')) {

        // Trying to create a variable that pulls in the number of items
        being used in the section (e.g. 'beerspecialnumber' which might be equal to 4) 

        ${${'sectionsarray['.$i.']'}.'number'} = $_POST[$sectionsarray[$i].'number'];

        //Another example of a failed attempt at a dynamically named variable 
        ${'sectionsarray'.[$i].'sectiontitle'} = $_POST[$sectionsarray[$i].'sectiontitle'];

        //Based on the number of products in a section, I create more variables for each 
        product - $q is the number of products, $i is the section number

        for($q=1; $q<=${${'sectionsarray['.$i.']'}.'number'}; $q++) {
            ${$sectionsarray[$i].$q.'title'} = $_POST[$sectionsarray[$i].$q.'title'];
            ${$sectionsarray[$i].$q.'titlesize'} = $_POST[$sectionsarray[$i].$q.'titlesize'];
            ...
```

The $_POST statements are pulling in the data from the form, but the code I'm using to try and create the variable names which are used in the generator doesn't seem to be working. In the sample code above, say "**beerspecials**" is the value of **$sectionblock1**, I'm trying to create variables by the name of "**beerspecialsnumber**", "**beerspecialssectiontitle**", "**beerspecials1title**" (for the first beer special product), and "**beerspecials1titlesize**" (for the font size of that title). All of these are used in the HTML generator.

Basically, I'm trying to take the section names in use, put them into an array, use the values from that array to create variable names with string text at the end of them.

Is there a way to do this? I've tried countless combinations and searched all over this site, but can't seem to figure it out?

Comment: Don't use variable variables, but arrays instead.

Comment: "dynamically create the variable names" is usually a red flag. Don't let input overwrite `$_POST`, `$_SESSION`, `$user` etc!

Comment: As @zerkms says: try to format your input into nested arrays. Even your starting vars have a suspicious format: `sectionblock1`. Sounds like you want `$_POST['sectionblock'][1]` and `$_POST['sections'][4]['title']` etc. That depends on your input names: `name="sections[4][title]"` etc

Comment: Thanks all...sounds like I have some more research in front of me. I've been trying to teach myself all of this and had this form working in what was probably the least efficient way, but I know nothing about nested arrays on the form inputs. I'll start digging.